# i2c + 7 segement serial display + ATtiny85

Tags: arduino, i2c, 7segmentdisplay

I have a project that requires a 7 segment display and I was trying to get away with using the smallest micro controller possible.

Does anyone see any problems with connecting an ATtiny85 to a 7 segment display or have an experience with it?

https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/407

Comment: It doesn't have enough pins to drive the display on its own, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It only needs 3 pins max to drive the display. Please see the link.

Comment: I saw the link. You said "7 segment display", not "7 segment display module via I2C/SPI/UART".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I will change. Sorry for the incorrect header.

Comment: It seems to me that if you're going to use that module anyways then you may as well reprogram the on-board MCU do do what you need.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What are your thoughts, though on i2c or serial uart?

Comment: Personally I'd prefer I2C unless I was stuck using a device that didn't support it and bit-banging it would be too much of a problem.

Comment: Smallest physically or code size or smallest what?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much a resounding "yes it will work". Mind the code size limit (8kb). Ignacio's comment of just changing the Display's onboard ATMega code would be a better option really.